# Uploading to user's google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Our application generates files and we want to upload the files in the google drives of our clients.
Does anyone know where is the getting started?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive API has an example of how you can archive this [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads).
Hope this help